# is Ruby em-websocket blocking?

Tags: ruby, websocket, em-websocket

I'm writing a ruby program that has 2 threads. One that listens on an incoming UDP connection and another that broadcasts on a websocket from which browsers on the client side read.I'm using the em-websocket gem. However, My UDP listener thread never gets called and it looks like the code stays within the websocket initialization code. I'm guessing because em-websocket is blocking, but I haven't been able to find any info online that suggests that. Is it an error on my side? I'm kinda new to ruby so I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
require 'json'
require 'em-websocket'
require 'socket'

socket=nil
text="default"
$x=0

EventMachine.run do
EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
  ws.onopen    { 
            ws.send "Hello Client!"
            socket=ws
            $x=1
        }

  ws.onmessage { |msg| socket.send "Pong: #{msg}" }
  ws.onclose   { puts "WebSocket closed" }
end
end
def listen()
puts "listening..."
s = UDPSocket.new
s.bind(nil, 3000)
while 1<2 do
  text, sender = s.recvfrom(1024)     
  puts text
  if $x==1 then
    socket.send text      
  end   
end
end

t2=Thread.new{listen()}
t2.join
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`em-websocket` is non-blocking, however `UDPSocket#recv_from` is. Might be better to just use EventMachine's `open_datagram_socket` instead.

Another thing to note: you should not expose `socket` as a "global" variable. Every time somebody connects the reference to the previously connected client will be lost. Maybe make some sort of repository for socket connections, or use an observer pattern to broadcast messages when something comes in. What I would do is have a dummy object act as an observer, and whenever a socket is connected/disconnect you register/unregister from the observer:

```
require 'observer'

class Dummy
  include Observable

  def receive_data data
    changed true
    notify_observers data
  end
end

# ... later on ...

$broadcaster = Dummy.new

class UDPHandler < EventMachine::Connection
  def receive_data data
    $broadcaster.receive_data data
  end
end

EventMachine.run do
  EM.open_datagram_socket "0.0.0.0", 3000, UDPHandler

  EM::WebSocket.start :host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080 do |ws|
    ws.onopen do
      $broadcaster.add_observer ws
    end

    ws.onclose do
      $broadcaster.delete_observer ws
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

The whole point of EventMachine is to abstract away from the basic socket and threading structure, and handle all the asynchronous bits internally. It's best not to mix the classical libraries like `UDPSocket` or `Thread` with EventMachine stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I figured out that my websocket send call is blocking and I'm guessing it's because of the "socket=ws" statement. I'm not exactly sure what an observer is, but I'll look it up and try to use that. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm initializing the websocket in a method and want to use the socket handle in another method, how else can I do that other than this way? The reference's scope seems to not extend globally. I'm not sure why though. Is scope different in ruby as compared to Java/C etc?

Comment: Alright. I figured out the problem. I hadn't defined the variable socket with a '$' sign. So it wasn't in global scope. I didn't know about the scope differences in ruby. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: Yeah any local variable (a variable with no sigil - `$`, `@` or `@@`) is not visible in a method defined using `def`. However the main thing you want to remember is that you may have multiple connections: `ws` won't always refer to the same connection!

Comment: Yup. Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the code to keep track of all open connections. Instead of using ws, I changed it to @ws. So now I have all connection handles in an array and I send a message to each one of them.

Comment: Yeah that's basically what `Observable` does, just manages it all for you so that you don't have to ;)